# Injecting list of generics in Spring 4.1

Tags: java, spring, list, generics, dependency-injection

The following issue was encountered while upgrading Spring 3.2 -> 4.1

There is a `Metadata` hierarchy, like: `AMetadata extends Metadata`,
 `BMetadata extends Metadata` etc.

There is a `Processor` hierarchy, like:

`abstract Processor<M extends Metadata>`,

`AProcessor extends Processor<AMetadata>`,

`BProcessor extends Processor<BMetadata>` etc

There is a service containing an injected `List` of processors, like this:

`@Inject
private List<Processor<Metadata>> processors;`

While this worked perfectly in Spring 3.2, with Spring 4.1.0 (and 4.0 as well) it fails to inject list members. Going into debug, it was discovered that:
`Processor<Metadata>.isAssignableFrom(BProcessor) == false` and this causes Processor beans not to be matched as eligible candidates for injection.

A possible hack-looking solution is to declare Processors as follows:

`BProcessor<Metadata> extends Processor<BMetadata>` - that works, but looks a bit weird. Another option is to use `List<Processor<? extends Metadata>>`, but this requires some code changes elsewhere to be compilable and causes a lot of type-safety-check warnings in classes which relied on generics.

So the question is, how to handle this case properly? Did anyone encountered something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Autowiring based on generics was one of the new features in Spring4. AFAIK they were ignored in previous versions. More info here: https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics

So I can't think of any other solution than you already pointed out: `List<Processor<? extends Metadata>>`.

Answer (score 0):

Also see video here Spring Framework on Java 8 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-_aWK8T_YMI that explains this. Generic type information was ingored till 4.0 Spring release. Now, they are taking into account.